# Is it possible to use character codes instead of < and > in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a perl script that generates an indexed search file for my website. Part of the functionality is that it excludes anything between < and > characters to avoid indexing tag contents. This has always worked fine, until recently when I included some javascript on all my pages that contains < and > characters.

Before I investigate modifying a perl script that I currently find bamboozling, I'm wondering if it's possible to use character codes instead of < and > characters in my javascript?

The specific lines of code that need < and > characters omitted are:

```
let foo = bar.filter(ele => parseInt(ele)>0 && ele.length ==4);
```

```
document.write('<link href="'+morefoo+'morebar.css"/>');
```

Comment: You probably should just skip searching text in your `<script>` tags entirely.

Comment: No it is not possible to do what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe possible with eval, but *eval* <shudder>

Comment: @Sanjay `if (a &lt; b)` throws an error when parsed as JavaScript.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) instead of changing all of your JS code, either fix your Perl script or simply load the JS from a separate file. The second one is probably the simplest possible solution that is most correct anyway. But the Perl code is likely to give you other trouble in the future that you probably don't anticipate right now.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for this, it's the most lateral solution. However, part of my javascript was to determine which directory the page has been archived in and find the path to the script and style files, hence including the script in the html. But I got around it by just including links to the various possible relative locations of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
document.write('<link href="'+morefoo+'morebar.css"/>');
```

do this

```
var css = document.createElement('link');
css.href = morefoo+'morebar.css';
css.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.head.appendChild(css);
// or the last line for OLD browsers (i.e. IE)
document.getElementsByTagName('head'][0].appendChild(css);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips you can try:

1. First Avoid arrow function, instead pass a anonymous function inside **filter** method and return the value explicitly.
2. For the statement **parseInt(ele)>0**, use a function like **isPositive(number)**. Create this method and load that method seperately before executing your actual file.
3. As @Jaromanda mentioned in previous answer how you can you load stylesheet dynamically.

These three steps will surely help you to meet your requirements.

Comment: "*Create this method and load that method seperately before executing your actual file"*  if doing that, why not just load all JavaScript separately to begin with, which means you wouldn't need to make a separate `isPositive` code?